# LG 34WN750 monitor crash?

Tags: nvidia, monitor, lg

I'm not sure why this is happening. I turn on my computer, do some work, and all of a sudden it just crashes. I have my monitor connected to rtx 3090 via hdmi, with AMD ryzen cpu. Is this a monitor hardware problem?

[image]

Comment: or video card. it was the video card when it happened to me.

Comment: @David how did you fix it? Given that I've been using rtx 3090 just fine with my two dell monitors, then it must be an issue with the lg monitor...

Comment: Had to replace the video card. Just because 1 port works does not mean the other does. I would be trying the monitor on another computer first.

Comment: @David I'll try a different hdmi port and a different computer to see if it works. Thanks.